# convert date format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I would like to convert the date data in the csv file from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd using d3.

I tried the following:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(data, error) {

          dataset = data;
          //alert(dataset.length);
        //alert(error);


          for(var x=0;x<dataset.length;x++)
        {


                ....

                date = parseDate(dataset[x].date);
                compid = dataset[x].compid
    }
})
```

My csv file data:
compid,name,builds,checkins,date

```
1,trf_errorcheckdocs,0,0,1/1/2013
1,trf_errorcheckdocs,0,0,2/1/2013
1,trf_errorcheckdocs,0,0,3/1/2013
```

Comment: You need to parse the dates into `Date` objects (as you're doing already) and define a date formatter for converting back into strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using slashes, not dashed, so your format should be like `'%d/%m/%Y'`. Then you need to first parse the string, then reformat it. The following function should take care of it.

```
function reformat (d) {
 return d3.time.format('%Y/%m/%d')(d3.time.format('%m/%d/%Y').parse(d));
}
```

Comment: this works fine. I have a query. First we are parsing the date which is of m/d/y format and typecasting to the specified format of Y/m/d. am i correct?